# categorification of the $\Gamma$ function?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, it.information-theory

Is there a combinatorial or information-theoretical meaning to $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$ ?

---

The identity $\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^\infty x^{n+1} e^{-x} \, dx = n!$ suggests something is being permuted on the left hand side.

I am tempted to read this as $(-\frac{1}{2})! = \sqrt{\pi}$ --- Formulas involving the Gamma function are in a way ubiquitous, but I don't

We analytically continue $\Gamma(z)$ to values $z = x + iy$ and $x < 0$ but for $x$ positive and $y = 0$ the Gamma function interpolates the factorials in a nice - straigthfoward way.

[image]

If I have a bunch of numbers adding $p_1 + \dots + p_n = 1$ maybe I can say the probabilities are themselves squares of some other values: $p_i = x_i^2$  then:
$$ x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 = 1 $$
is the equation of a perfect sphere.  The [volume of this sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) is :
$$ \mathrm{Vol} \big( x_1^2 + \dots + x_{n+1}^2 = 1 \big) 
= \frac{\;\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$$
this is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could say that this is related to 
the normalization constant of the standard normal distribution, since (with change of variables $x = t^2/2$)
$$ \Gamma(1/2) = \int_0^\infty x^{-1/2}\; e^{-x}\; dx = \sqrt{2} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\; dt$$
and thence to the asymptotics of ${2n \choose n}$:
$$ {2n \choose n} 2^{-2n} \sim \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}} \ \text{as}\ n \to \infty$$
where the left side is the probability that the result of $2n$ fair coin flips is $n$ heads and $n$ tails, and the right side can be obtained from the normal distribution...

Comment: so much chatter on categorification nobody can explain the origin of $\sqrt{\pi}$ on this site? your answer is as good as any